# Can I undo a 301 redirect? Will it penalize my ranking?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm in charge of building a website for a company that made a mess.

They own domain `xxx.it` (`xxx` is not the real domain, just a placeholder).

Some years ago they 301 redirected `xxx.it` to `xxx.com` (they just changed TLDs).

Last year they 301 redirected `xxx.com` to `yyy.com` (so, they actually changed domains).

Now, after 13 months, the company failed and the new leadership wants me to undo everything and 301 redirect from `yyy.com` to `xxx.it`.

So:

1. [301 redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) is permanent. So, conceptually it's wrong to undo it. What happens if I undo it? Will my ranking be penalized, even if a significant amount of time has passed (13 months)?
2. Will crawlers detect a loop (even if i remove any 301 redirect from `xxx.it` and theorically break the loop)? Here is the potential loop: `xxx.it` -> `xxx.com` -> `yyy.com` -> `xxx.it` -> etc...

All of the articles I found on the web are quite old and not clear about this topic, that's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you move to a new domain you will lose some of your ranking.  Google has stated that a percentage of "link juice" will flow through 301s, but I highly doubt that it would follow more than one hop.

Unless there is a business need to move domains, I'd say settle down and STOP MOVING.  If there are a significant number of inbound links to one of the iterations of the domain, then settle on that one.  Otherwise, pick one and adjust all of your 301s to go to the new.